# I am trying to use MYSQL SELECT with many-to many relationship tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

students, modules and students_modules (which is a linking table). What I am trying to do id selecting the modules associated with a particular student. I know that this is wrong but what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM modules 
WHERE id = (SELECT moduleID FROM students_modules WHERE studentID = '123')
```

So could any one help me please.

Comment: just put IN in place of " = "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JOIN` to link the three tables with each others:

```
SELECT 
  s.StudentName,
  m.Id,
  m.Name AS ModuleName
FROM modules                AS m
INNER JOIN students_modules AS sm ON m.id         = sm.moduleID
INNER JOIN students         AS  s ON sm.studentID = s.id
WHERE WHERE ms.studentID = '123';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try IN instead of = for your subquery:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM modules     
WHERE id IN (SELECT moduleID FROM students_modules WHERE studentID = '123')
```

Comment: This will help if there are more than one `moduleID` for each `studentID`

Comment: Yep, OP suggests it's a many to many relationship and intuitively, a student would be taking more than one module, figured this could be OP's error